# Can you specify the JRE version an applet should run?

Tags: jre, java-applet

Is it possible to specify the JRE version a Java applet should execute in the browser? e.g. If I have Java 7u17 and Java7u72 installed (32-bit) can the applet request 7u17 to be used?

Similarly, if I have Java 6u26 32-bit and Java 6u81 64-bit installed, can the applet request 6u26 32-bit?